# How to read fields from csv with whitespaces and period in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, reader

I am trying to read the entire column of a csv into my Spring Batch reader, however I am getting an error because one of my fields have an whitespace and period, so my code does not works as expect.
How can I fix my lineMapper to work also with fields that has an whitespace and period?

Example of csv:

```
"Name","Last name", "Date","Street. Name"
"test_name", "abc", "2010.10.02", "street test"
```

Code:

```
@Configuration
public class testReader{
    @Bean("testReader)
    public FlatFileItemReader<TestDTO> csvFileReader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<TestDTO> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        Resource file = csvFileResource();
        reader.resource(file)
        reader.linesToSkip(1) // Skip header row if needed
        reader.lineMapper(csvLineMapper())
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultLineMapper<TestDTO> csvLineMapper() {
        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setNames("Name","Last name", "Date","Street. Name");

        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<YourDataClass> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(TestDTO.class);

        DefaultLineMapper<TestDTO> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);

        return lineMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public Resource[] csvFileResource() throws IOException {
        // Specify the folder path where your CSV files are generated
        Resource[] resources = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("file:input/*.csv");
        if (resources.length == 0) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("No CSV files found in the specified folder.");
        }
        return resources;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Parse error
```

Comment: @xerx593 I get the same Parse error of the csv data with the code that you provided.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think that the Spring classes have enough sophistication to do detailed CSV. Commons would be better

Comment: @g00se I am trying to search if is possible to override some method of the class that I am using to handle header fields that has whitespace or period.

Comment: I would go specialized if I were you

Comment: Having said that, `DefaultLineTokenizer` seems to be able to cope with the input you posted.  *Resource file = csvFileResource();* You're calling a method (not well named) that returns an array but assigning it to a single (non-array) variable

Comment: The method returns a single resource that is the csv that I want to read, if I change the "Street. Name" to "Street Name" the code works.